# Python: find element by a href

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I used webdriver Chrome to scrape data from a website, but I don't know how to extract data from a href.

HTM:

```
<div class="buySearchResultContent">
  <ul id="CARS_LIST_DATA">
      <li class="seo_list" data-seo_name="440285">
        <div class="buySearchResultContentImg">
          <a href="carinfo-333285.php">
            <img src="carpics/9400180056/290x200/20180305101502854_4567823.jpg" srcset="carpics/9400180056/290x200/20180305101502854_9098765.jpg 290w, carpics/9400180056/435x300/20180305101502854_00000.jpg 435w , carpics/9400180056/720x520/20180305101502854_00001.jpg 720w" sizes="(min-width: 992px) 75vw, 90vw" alt="auto">
          </a>
```

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.asdf.com.tw/price-02.php?v=3&brand=lisa&model=lulu&year1=2009&year2=2018&page=1"
driver.get(url)
content=driver.find_element_by_class_name('buySearchResultContentImg')
print(content)
```

What I want to extract is "carinfo-333285.php". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided to extract the `href` attribute you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- `css_selector` :

  ```
  myHref = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.buySearchResultContentImg > a").get_attribute("href")
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  myHref = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='buySearchResultContentImg']/a").get_attribute("href")
  ```

Comment: a question, if there are not only one href I want to extract, can I use this to find all with the same patent? TIA

Comment: @Lara19 Each `<a>` tag will contain only one `href` attribute. Incase there are multiple `<a>` tags you have to construct the _Locator Strategy_ to point to the desired `<a>` tag to retrieve the `href` attribute. Let me know if I am able to answer your counter question.

Comment: I just updated them above :)  I tried your code but found that sometimes they have several hrefs in one page, and I can only extract one. So would you mind take a look? Thanks

Comment: @Lara19 If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new ticket as per your new requirements following stackoverflow standards. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out. For this question I am reverting back the question to the original scope.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    a_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, 
                               "buySearchResultContentImg")]/a[@href]')
    link = a_element.get_attribute("href")
except NoSuchElementException:
    link = None
```

Comment: `if a_element:` is absolutely redundant as if link not found you'll get `NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about python, Please try this

```
Jpg_href= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='buySearchResultContentImg']/a[@href='carinfo-333285.php']").get_attribute("href")
```